# keep getting php white screen of death when i try to add a confirmation box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make a confirmation box when a user deletes an entry which is done from the `echo "<a href=\"delete.php?sqluid=".$row[sqluid]."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";`statement. tried using an "onlick" operator and some javascript that would do an href redirect to the delete statement. tried about 6 different sets of code i found on this site but i dont think i am implementing it correctly. keep getting an undefined constant error when i check the php log

```
<?php

//Get database credentials
require 'config.php';

// connect to the mysql database server.
mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpass);
//select the database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Cannot select database');

require 'header.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM ring29 ORDER BY `ring29`.`ospfarea`,`dot1q`,`subnethost` ASC;";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

//Count the number of rows returned
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Table header
echo "<div><table id=\"tableheader\" bgcolor=\"#4382b5\">\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;         Sql UID...........</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;  Market:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;      Market Code:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;  OSPF Area:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;  Primary Tag:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;  802.1Q:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;  Subnet/Host:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp; IPv6 Subnet/Host:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;Slot/Port:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;CMTS GW Node:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;Slot/Port:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;IPv6 Subnet/host:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;Subnet/Host:</td>\n";
echo "<td>&nbsp;802.1Q:</td>\n";
echo "<tr>";
echo "</table></div>";
if ($count !== 0) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                echo "<div class=\"addform\"><form method='get' action=\"update.php\">\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row[sqluid]."\" name=\"sqluid\">\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"market\" value=\"".$row[market]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"mktcode\" value=\"".$row[mktcode]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"ospfarea\" value=\"".$row[ospfarea]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"primarytag\" value=\"".$row[primarytag]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"dot1q\" value=\"".$row[dot1q]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"subnethost\" value=\"".$row[subnethost]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"ipv6subnethost\" value=\"".$row[ipv6subnethost]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"slotport\" value=\"".$row[slotport]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"cmtsgwnode\" value=\"".$row[cmtsgwnode]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"slotport1\" value=\"".$row[slotport1]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"ipv6subnethost1\" value=\"".$row[ipv6subnethost1]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"subnethost1\" value=\"".$row[subnethost1]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"dot1q1\" value=\"".$row[dot1q1]."\"/>\n";
                                echo "  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Update Row\">\n";
                                echo "<a href=\"delete.php?sqluid=".$row[sqluid]."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";
                    }
                echo "</table><br />\n";
        } else {
                echo "<b><center>NO DATA</center></b>\n";
        }
        echo "<div>Add Row:</div>\n";
        echo "<div class=\"addform\"><form method='get' action=\"add.php\">\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"sqluid\" value=\"Enter unique number\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"market\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"mktcode\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"ospfarea\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"primarytag\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"dot1q\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"subnethost\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"ipv6subnethost\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"slotport\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"cmtsgwnode\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"slotport1\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"ipv6subnethost1\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"subnethost1\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"text\" name=\"dot1q1\"/>\n".
        "       <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/add.png\" alt=\"Add Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Add Row\">\n".
        "</form></div>";
?>
<div>
<br />
<b>Legend:</b>
<br />
<img alt="Add" src="images/add.png"> Add a row after entering the correct information.<br />
<img alt="Update" src="images/update.png"> Update a row after editing it.<br />
<img alt "Delete" src="images/delete.png"> Delete a row.<br />
<br />

<form method="get" action="http://<ip address removed>">
<button type="submit">Back</button>
</form>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the opening <?php?

Comment: it is above the first line and closing is between the "<form></div>"; and <div> .  opening didnt show up in the above window for some reason

Comment: Stick an ini_set('display_errors','on'); right after your PHP opening and you will have an error message revealed. It will probably tell you the line number of your issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but you know you don't actually have to end and begin a new echo for each line, right?

Comment: changed the $row[sqluid] ought to be $row['sqluid'] and all the others and retried what i did before with the ini_set('display_errors','on'); added, still getting blank screen with no errors listed with all the methods i previously tried

Comment: You have to get the line the error is coming from. If it's not showing on the screen, it must be in the PHP log. This is really difficult without that information. But, to continue stabbing into the dark... check perms on config.php and header.php to be sure they load. After that, start putting die('made it this far...'); into the file, move it further and further down the file to help you identify how far it makes it before something errors.

Answer (score 0):

$row[sqluid] ought to be $row['sqluid'] and there are several more like it as you build your input elements.

Comment: I made the changes as shown in my actual program but still nothing. i know i need to somehow make a 'on click' trigger to on the line: echo "<a href=\"delete.php?sqluid=".$row[sqluid]."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";   but cant seem to make it work